# Loading a video in mpv media player sometimes freezes my desktop (Ubuntu 21.10)

Tags: freeze, amdgpu, mpv-media-player

Output in journal:

```
Nov 26 00:36:51 ubuntupartition kernel: [drm:amdgpu_job_timedout [amdgpu]] *ERROR* ring uvd timeout, signaled seq=61096, emitted seq=61098
Nov 26 00:36:51 ubuntupartition kernel: [drm:amdgpu_job_timedout [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Process information: process  pid 0 thread  pid 0
Nov 26 00:36:56 ubuntupartition kernel: [drm:amdgpu_dm_commit_planes [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Waiting for fences timed out!
Nov 26 00:36:57 ubuntupartition kernel: [drm:amdgpu_dm_commit_planes [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Waiting for fences timed out!
```

I'm running a AMD Radeon R9 380 4gb GPU and a Ryzen 5 5600x processor.

When it happens I'm still able to do things like move my mouse and play and pause my music. I've also noticed that it is much more prone to happen after my computer has been running for a few hours. After it happens the only way to fix it I've found is to hard reboot, Alt+SysRq+REISUB doesn't seem to do anything.

I've tried upgrading Ubuntu from 20.04, to 21.04, to 21.10, but no dice. Same goes for upgrading my kernel, upgrading to 5.15 didn't help.

Any help is appreciated, have a great day all.

Comment: You should have a choice of video out devices which can be seen with `mpv -vo help`. Try one of these and see if it rectifies the problem. Perhaps something like: `mpv -vo xv input.mp4` might be a safe option?

Comment: @andrew.46 I tried this out, unfortunately it froze and I got the same output in my journal log. However, this time the freeze happened while the video was playing, rather than it happening after. Because of the fact that the freezes tend to happen more often after a few hours of uptime it will be tricky to test all the viable options, but I'll try over the course of the next few days.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't thoroughly tested, but I'm pretty sure I've found the culprit. In the Ubuntu package, `mpv.conf`is set so that `hwdec=vaapi` by default. The mpv manual says that this can cause issues and recommends outright deleting the config file, but I just changed it to `hwdec=no` which is the default.

I'll update this if I continue to face the same issues but for now I'm fairly confident this is the fix.